# How to validate decimal numbers precision using Joi

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

I am validating the request body for one of the API I am working on to insert the data in the DB.
DB has precision as 3.

Using Joi, I am validating as

```
f_num: Joi.number().precision(3).required()
```

My understanding was that it'll only allow decimal precision upto 3 and should throw an error if there's a number like **1.345678** saying the precision should be 3.

But it goes through and while inserting the data , it rounds to 3 decimal places in the database.

Is there a way to check the exact precision using Joi? I tried searching online but not able to find any answers.

Answer (score 1):

Using precision will by default just round the decimals to the specified maximum. If you want it to fail the validation instead, set convert to false as per the documentation:

```
joi.validate(objectToValidate, schema, {convert:false});
```

Comment: The schema has many other elements as well. Is it possible to validate only one of them?

Comment: @neil Sorry for the late response, I don't think it's possible to only validate one, but you can just create 2 schemas, and make 2 validations

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to disabled convert globally you can just use

```
f_num: Joi.number().precision(3).prefs({ convert: false }).required()
```

source: https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.9.1#anyprefsoptions---aliases-preferences-options